# To open application it it's not running

Tags: c++, macos

I have a service and an application developed for Mac OSX. The service needs to contain logic that if the application is not running already, then it should open the application.

To open the application, I am using :

system("open /Users/adsmaster/client/client &");

My question is: How do I add the logic to track if the application is running or not? If it's not, only then should the system() call be made as shown above.Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I'd recommend *against* using `system` to start the new process, as the `system` function starts a shell to run your program. Instead use `fork` to create a new process and then one of the `exec` family of functions to start the other program.

Comment: You could have the application "lock" some named resource while it runs.  A file, a Unix domain socket, etc.

Comment: More related to your problem, you could use some kind of shared resource that's available in the file-system to see if the process is running or not. And then pick one that is removed automatically when the process exits for whatever reason.